# Hangfire not always execute retries tasks code and sometimes randomly marked them as succeeded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

*.Net Core (3.0.0), Hangfire.AspNetCore (1.7.7), Hangfire.SqlServer(1.7.7)*

---

**Case 1**

I faced with an issue that sometimes hangfire do nothing(no code execution) but marked tasks as succeeded. Cannot find a pattern it happens randomly but pretty often 50/50.

```
//Entry point is .Net Core API
[Route("pull-daily")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PullDaily([FromQuery] int hour, int minutes)
{
    paymentsService.PullDaily(hour, minutes);
    return Ok();
}

internal class PaymentsService : IPaymentsService
{
    private readonly IPaymentsProvider _provider;
    private readonly IJobManager _jobManager;

    public PaymentsService(IPaymentsProvider provider, IJobManager jobManager)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _jobManager = jobManager;
    }

    public void PullDaily(int hour, int minute)
    {
        _jobManager.AddRecurring(
            () => _provider.Pull(),
            () => Cron.Daily(hour, minute));
    }
}

internal class PaymentsProvider : IPaymentsProvider
{
//...
    public void Pull()
    {
        throw new Exception("TEST EX " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
//...
}

public class JobManager : IJobManager
{
    public void AddRecurring(Expression<Action> action, Func<string> cronExpression)
    {
        handle(() => RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(action, cronExpression));
    }

    private void handle(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Case 1 IMG]

---

**Case 2**

I've find out that if I simplified my code to couple lines there is another issue appears Hangfire still sometimes do nothing(no code execution) just marked attempts as failed with the error ***Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob Value cannot be null...***

```
public class JobManager : IJobManager
{
    public void Test()
    {
        throw new Exception("TEST EX " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }

    public void AddRecurring(Expression<Action> action, Func<string> cronExpression)
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Test(), cronExpression);
    }
}
```

[image: Case 2 IMG]
**Startup.cs**

```
//...
// Add Hangfire services.
services.AddHangfire(config => config
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
    {
        CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
        UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
        UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
        DisableGlobalLocks = true
    }));

// Add the processing server as IHostedService
services.AddHangfireServer();
//...
```

Please guys, help me find out what is wrong here.

Comment: I failed to reproduce the issue based on the existing code . Where and how did you call the background jobs ?Could you share a complete simple demo which can reproduce your issue,so that we could review and debug code?

Comment: Entry point is WebAPI. I've added to the description.